# Using find to delete some files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I'm trying to delete some files using `find` like the line below.

`find / -name "file1" -o -name "file2" -delete`

My problem is that this line returns true if it finds "file1" but do not delete it, just "file2".

I've tried to use parentheses, but it's not working too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show what your command line looked like when you "tried to use parentheses".  When you write:

```
find / -name "file1" -o -name "file2" -delete
```

The order-of-operations means that the expression becomes, effectively:

```
( -name "file1" ) -o ( -name "file2" -delete )
```

So of course it only deletes `file2`.  If you change your parentheses it should work just fine:

```
find / \( -name "file1" -o -name "file2" \) -delete
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. This is my first time. Your solution is not working too. This way don't delete anything, not even the last file of the list.

Comment: @bob Replace `-delete` with `-print` and post results. If it doesn't find anything then there is nothing to be found ... maybe there are some other characters in the file names.

Comment: I found something. Using just files in the list everything works perfectly. When there are folders, nothing is deleted. But the flag `-print` always work.

Comment: You can't use `-delete` to delete a directory.